# How prevent to load onCreate of Fragment before Java?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin

Hey I tried to do this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) now I got the problem that when I start the app it crashes because the arguments of my fragment are null. I found an answer that I have to remove the fragment from my content_main.xml, but when I do this the app starts but behaves weird and I dont think this is the right answer for the problem.

So the onCreate() of my MainActivityFragment is called before the java code so I got problems with this lines:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    page = this.arguments.getInt("someInt", 0)
    title = this.arguments.getString("someTitle")
}
```

Whats the right solution for the problem?

My code is on [github](https://github.com/Gnadi/Alfred.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your **GitHub** project, you are implementing `Fragment` instantiation in a wrong way.
When you invoque  `var fragment = MainActivityFragment()`, you create new Instance of your fragment but no `arguments` are provided, so, when your fragment `onCreate` method is called, arguments are `null` and that is the reason why your app crashes.

To fix your app crash you need to implement fragment instantiations on the following way:

**MainActivityFragment** (Edited)

```
// Wrap new instance function inside companion object
companion object {
    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    fun newInstance(page: Int, title: String): MainActivityFragment {
        val fragmentFirst = MainActivityFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putInt("someInt", page)
        args.putString("someTitle", title)
        fragmentFirst.arguments = args
        return fragmentFirst
    }
}

//...
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if(null != this.arguments) {
        page = this.arguments.getInt("someInt", 1)
        title = this.arguments.getString("someTitle")
    }
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter**

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
    when (position) {
        0 // Fragment # 0 - Ensure to return a new fragment instance with valid arguments
        -> return MainActivityFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1")
        1 // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
        -> return SecondFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2")
        else -> return null
    }
}
```

Do not forget to wrap **SecondFragment** `newInstance` function within companion object.

Comment: thank you for your answer I changed the project but the app keeps crashing because of a null pointer exception here "page = this.arguments.getInt("someInt", 0)". I pushed my changes in case i did some wrong changes. I also added the fragment in my content_main.xml

Comment: @JohannesGnadlinger Remove included content_main layout, that's will cause the same problem

Comment: You are welcome @JohannesGnadlinger!, I will apreciate if you accept my question edition as well